# Symfony 4 - Delete on cascade doesn't work

Tags: symfony, cascade

I've a Symfony 4 project, and I have these entities :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupeValidateursRepository")
 */
class GroupeValidateurs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Validateur", inversedBy="groupeValidateurs", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $validateurs;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="groupe")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->validateurs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Validateur[]
     */
    public function getValidateurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->validateurs;
    }

    public function addValidateur(Validateur $validateur): self
    {
        if (!$this->validateurs->contains($validateur)) {
            $this->validateurs[] = $validateur;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeValidateur(Validateur $validateur): self
    {
        if ($this->validateurs->contains($validateur)) {
            $this->validateurs->removeElement($validateur);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getListeNomValidateurs()
    {
        $liste = [];

        foreach ($this->validateurs as $validateur) {
            $nom = $validateur->getValidateur()->getFullName();
            $liste[] = $nom;
        }

        return $liste;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->setGroupe($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->removeElement($user);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($user->getGroupe() === $this) {
                $user->setGroupe(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsersValidateurs()
    {
        $users = [];

        foreach ($this->validateurs as $validateur) {
            $unUserValidateur = $validateur->getValidateur();
            $users[] = $unUserValidateur;
        }

        return $users;
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Gedmo\Sortable\Sortable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SortablePosition;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ValidateurRepository")
 */
class Validateur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SortablePosition
     */
    private $ordre;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GroupeValidateurs", mappedBy="validateurs")
     */
    private $groupeValidateurs;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $validateur;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groupeValidateurs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getOrdre(): ?int
    {
        return $this->ordre;
    }

    public function setOrdre(int $ordre): self
    {
        $this->ordre = $ordre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidateur(): ?User
    {
        return $this->validateur;
    }

    public function setValidateur(User $validateur): self
    {
        $this->validateur = $validateur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|GroupeValidateurs[]
     */
    public function getGroupeValidateurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->groupeValidateurs;
    }

    public function addGroupeValidateur(GroupeValidateurs $groupeValidateur): self
    {
        if (!$this->groupeValidateurs->contains($groupeValidateur)) {
            $this->groupeValidateurs[] = $groupeValidateur;
            $groupeValidateur->addValidateur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeGroupeValidateur(GroupeValidateurs $groupeValidateur): self
    {
        if ($this->groupeValidateurs->contains($groupeValidateur)) {
            $this->groupeValidateurs->removeElement($groupeValidateur);
            $groupeValidateur->removeValidateur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And, when I manage my groups, like this :

[image]

If I remove a "validateur", I would like my "validator" object to be removed from the database. So I tried, in my entity "validator", to add the "cascade = {" remove "}", on the attribute "groupValidators" and "validator", but when I delete a validator of my group, the validator object is not removed from the database

Comment: Are you using `$obj->remove()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late, but for those still coming here be careful with typo :
use `cascade = {"remove"}` not `cascade = {" remove "}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the owning side of the relationship cascades the "remove" towards the inverse side.

If you've done that, the example code is still missing any kind of `EntityManager::flush()` call to persist those pending changes towards the orm.